# Maximum number of multi index tables an account can hold

Tags: multi-index

Is there a limit on the number of multi index tables an account can hold? Is it limited by the RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not any limit for number of table but the table require space in your RAM so it is depended on payer's RAM.